# get null pointer error when trying to getText

Tags: android

I am new to Android, so please forgive my ignorance. I have tried searching the forums, but haven't been able to find anything to get this to work. I am trying to use .getText().toString() (see below), but get a java.lang.NullPointerException error. I changed my setContentView so that it would look at the fragment_main.xml, but still returns a null for my different components. The goal of this is very simple, just to change the text on the TextView, since I am just getting started. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        Button changeTxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeText);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        changeTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = textView.getText().toString();

                if (text.contains("World")) {
                    textView.setText("Hello Android!");
                }
                else {
                    textView.setText(("Hello World!"));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }  
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Text"
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fllo, updated code:

XML fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change Text"
            android:id="@+id/btnChangeText1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

main activity

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }


    }


    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            Button changeTxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeText);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

            changeTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String text = textView.getText().toString();

                    if (text.contains("World"))
                    {
                        textView.setText("Hello Android!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textView.setText(("Hello World!"));
                    }
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: get rid of if part in your activity coz i don't see a viewgroup in the xml posted

Comment: What's the name of the layout file? (you're probably using findViewById on the wrong layout)

Comment: you also inflate the same `fragment_main`  layout that you set to activity in fragment also. post the stacktrace. the vies may belong to `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Raghunandan, where do I find the stacktrace? Like I said, I am very new to this. Also, I am using android studio rather than eclipse.

Comment: Not yet, Follo. I will probably have time tomorrow. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer - I think it will resolve all your problems. HTH

Answer (score 2):

The **NullPointerException** occurs because, it seems that you have the same layout for your `Activity` and your `Fragment`:

```
 // Activity
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

 // Fragment
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 return rootView;
```

You need to check if your views (TextView & Button) are in the right layout and not into aonther (I guess `activity_main`).

**Two solutions:**

- Copy/past your views inside `fragment_main` to `activity_main` and change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.
- Or let your views inside `fragment_main` and use the following code to find your view inside your `Fragment`, as follows:

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
      Button changeTxt = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnChangeText);
      final TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

      changeTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              String text = textView.getText().toString();

              if (text.contains("World")) {
                  textView.setText("Hello Android!");
              }
              else {
                  textView.setText(("Hello World!"));
              }
         }
      });
      return rootView;
  }
  ```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE:**

1 . Remove your *FrameLayout* inside `fragment_main`. Create a new layout named `activity_main` and add the *FrameLayout* into it (with an ***id***) as:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container" />
```

2 . Set this layout in `onCreate` method into your *Activity* like:

```
// onCreate method Activity
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

3 . Then, remove `static` in your *Fragment* declaration, this should be:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment ... { }
```

4 . Finally, when you try to find ids elements inside `onCreateView` method, you ***ALWAYS MUST*** to use the *inflated view* as:

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.some_id_example);
```

Voila! This should work now.

Comment: I tried pasting the code from the onCreate to onCreateView, but it is throwing an error on the findViewByID. "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @user1019838 You should update your question and post your new code. I'll help you I think it's not heavy to debug this ;) - Also maybe you forgot to add the inflated view to your findViewById method. See my answer, you should do `rootView.findViewById(...)`

Comment: I didn't need to remove `static` declaration of the `PlaceholderFragment`, and it still worked, thanks! However, is there a changelog of sorts where we can learn more about these changes? A lot of older tutorials don't cover fragments, and ADT seems to generate these _different_ projects, making learning difficult...